# Trying to run dynamic sql using a UDF in DB2

Tags: db2

I am very new to DB2 even though have experience in Oracle. I am not able to resolve this issue.I have a requirement where I need to find missing child records in the parent table .The parent table , child table and the join_key are all passed as input parameter.

I have tried this in a procedure was able to achieve this,  but the admin wants it in a function so that they can just use it in a select statment and get the result in a table format. Since the parent table ,  child table and the join_key are comming as input parement, I am not able to run them as dynamic sql.

```
create or replace function missing_child_rec(PARENT_TBL VARCHAR(255),JOIN_KEY VARCHAR(255),CHILD_TBL VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE(Key VARCHAR(255))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE V_SQL VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE C_SQL CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR S_SQL;
SET V_PARENT_TAB = PARENT_TBL;
SET V_KEY = JOIN_KEY;
SET V_CHILD_TAB = CHILD_TBL;
SET V_SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT '|| JOIN_KEY  || ' FROM ' || V_CHILD_TAB || ' A WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT ' ||V_KEY || '  FROM ' || V_PARENT_TAB || ' B WHERE A.'||JOIN_KEY || '= B.'||JOIN_KEY ||' )' ;

PREPARE S_SQL FROM V_SQL;
OPEN C_SQL;
CLOSE C_SQL;


RETURN
END
```

When I try to compile it , it says prepare is invalid , I have tried even execute immediate but that also gave error.Can you please help me with how to use dynamic sql in UDF or an alternative logic for this problem

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to solve this, here's one way.

If you already have a working stored-procedure that returns the correct result-set then you can call that stored-procedure from a pipelined table function. The idea is that a pipelined table function can consume the result-set and pipe it to the caller.

This will work on Db2-LUW v10.1 or higher, as long as the database is not partitioned over multiple nodes.
It may work on Db2-for-i v7.1 or higher.
It will not work with Db2 for Z/os at current versions.

Suppose your stored procedure is `sp_missing_child_rec` and it takes the same input parameters as the function you show in your question, and suppose the data type of the join column is varchar(100).

The pipelined wrapper table function would look something like this:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

create or replace function missing_child_rec(PARENT_TBL VARCHAR(255),JOIN_KEY VARCHAR(255),CHILD_TBL VARCHAR(255))
returns table ( join_column_value varchar(100))
begin
  declare v_rs result_set_locator varying;
  declare v_row      varchar(100); -- to match the join_column_datatype, adjust as necessary
  declare sqlstate char(5) default '00000';
  CALL sp_missing_child_rec( parent_tbl, join_key, child_tbl);
  associate result set locator (v_rs) with procedure sp_missing_child_rec ;
  allocate v_rscur cursor for result set v_rs;
  fetch from v_rscur into v_row;
  while ( sqlstate = '00000') do
      pipe(v_row);
      fetch from v_rscur into v_row;
  end while;
  return;
end@



select * from table(missing_child_rec( 'parent_table' , 'join_column', 'child_table'))
@
```

Comment: One thing to note is that a table function using the `PIPE` statement is not supported on database partitioned LUW database (i.e. a MPP configuration)